# How to set the whole chart to become wider in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot both line and bar chart that is too narrow to see because the legends are taking up two columns. How do I increase the width of the whole chart? my Googling doesn't yield anything. I have:

```
line_plot <- ggplot(data=compat,aes(x=year,y=savings,color=factor(banks))) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line",width=10) + 
  guides(col=guide_legend(ncol=2,title ="banks",)) + 
  ggtitle(class[i]) + 
  ylab("savings total") + 
  xlab("Year")
```

Comment: Can you provide your data, `compat`, or a piece of your data so that we can recreate your plot?

Comment: The width is only relevant relative to whatever device you are outputting the plot on. Typically the default device displays in a window that can be resized. If you are writing to a file (i.e. png, pdf, etc) then you specify the device width when you write the plot to a separate file.

Comment: ...my point being that the "width" of the resulting plot doesn't even come into play in the code you've shown. It would be specified in the _next_ step, when you actually create a file.

Answer (score 1):

```
pdf("myplot.pdf", height=6, width=12)
   print(line_plot)
dev.off()
```

Warning: The png() device uses different units for its height and width argument. The names of the interactive graphics devices varies between OSes.

```
 ?Devices
```

Comment: `ggsave` is recommended for ggplots, but the width argument is the same.

Comment: It's help page hints that it may use inches as the units, but it's rather unclear. It warns against using pixels but says it using the units of the chosen device. I guess you would need to experiment if you were using `ggsave` to dispatch to `png()`.

Comment: Maybe we're looking at different versions; I don't find it unclear. The `units` argument defaults to inches (regardless of device), but you can specify your preference. I don't see any mention of pixels, except in the `dpi` and `limitsize` arguments.

Comment: `ggsave` also takes care of any OS-variation, I believe.

Comment: Yes, it does appear to be a strenuous attempt to shield the user from the vagaries of R devices. I'm not sure this is an entirely good thing, since understanding device variations is part of learning to use R confidently, but I do see why it might be recommended for newbs. It wasn't clear that it should be any less error prone for experienced users. Looking at the code I see that inches _is_ the default for all devices, and I suppose I should have realized that from the help page's usage section. I see no detection of OS.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer this without sample data, but you might be able to put the legend inside the plot area, using

```
line_plot + theme(legend.justification=c(1,0), legend.position=c(1,0))
```

This positions the legend inside the plot area, at the bottom-right. You can also put the legend at the top or bottom of the plot using, e.g.:

```
line_plot + theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

There's a complete discussion of this in the outstanding reference [Cookbook for R](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_%28ggplot2%29/).